# Init array with bool values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

my attempt to init an array with a number of bool values using:

```
[myArray initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], 
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], 
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                         nil];
```

seems to fail since the debugger shows an empty array after this statement is carried out ... Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are `alloc`-ing the object, as well, i.e.:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...];
...
[myArray release];
```

Or:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...] autorelease];
```

Or:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...];
```

Comment: or better use NSArray arrayWithObjects: to do both at once

Comment: Sometimes it is preferable to alloc-init, to be able to release the array as soon as it is no longer needed. But either way works.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I found the bug. I did an initWithContentsOfFile that, when unsuccessful, should load the defaults. The missing link was that I had to alloc/init in case the loading from file fails.